# How to get From & To Ip Address from CIDR BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, geoip

BigQuery provides updated geoip2 public dataset [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=httparchive-explore&folder&organizationId&p=bigquery-public-data&d=geolite2&t=ipv4_city_blocks&page=table) [bigquery-publicdata -> geolite2 -> ipv4_city_blocks] which contains network column with IPv4 CIDR values.

How do I convert the CIDR values in the network column via BigQuery SQL (and not via a utility outside BigQuery) into start & end ip-address values so that I can find if an IP address is within a range or no? Would be helpful if you can provide the query to obtain the range ips for a CIDR value in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION cidrToRange(CIDR STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<start_IP STRING, end_IP STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var beg = CIDR.substr(CIDR,CIDR.indexOf('/'));
  var end = beg;
  var off = (1<<(32-parseInt(CIDR.substr(CIDR.indexOf('/')+1))))-1; 
  var sub = beg.split('.').map(function(a){return parseInt(a)});
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4); 
  var i32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
  i32[0]  = (sub[0]<<24) + (sub[1]<<16) + (sub[2]<<8) + (sub[3]) + off;
  var end = Array.apply([],new Uint8Array(buf)).reverse().join('.');
  return {start_IP: beg, end_IP: end};
"""; 
SELECT network, IP_range.*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geolite2.ipv4_city_blocks`,
UNNEST([cidrToRange(network)]) IP_range
```

It took about 60 sec to process all 3,037,858 rows with result like below

[image]

Comment: FYI - BigQuery deleted this table, so this answer doesn't work anymore. In the meantime here's my solution for Snowflake https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to check is, if that function already exists, so please refer to the [BigQuery Functions and Operators documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators).

If not, you need to use [Standard SQL User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) (UDF), which lets you create a function using another SQL expression or another programming language, such as JavaScript.

Keep in mind when using UDF JavaScript function, BigQuery initializes a JavaScript environment with the function's contents on every shard of execution. There is no optimization to avoid loading the environment, so it can slow down the query.

Regarding to [GeoIP2 City and Country CSV Databases](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-city-country-csv-databases/) site, there is a utility to convert 'network' column to start/end IPs or start/end integers. Refer to [Github](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip2-csv-converter) site for details.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do the job:

```
# replace with your source of IP addresses
# here I'm using the same Wikipedia set from the previous article
WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(contributor_ip, 'xxx', '0')  ip, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE contributor_ip IS NOT null  
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT city_name, SUM(c) c, ST_GeogPoint(AVG(longitude), AVG(latitude)) point
FROM (
  SELECT ip, city_name, c, latitude, longitude, geoname_id
  FROM (
    SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
    FROM source_of_ip_addresses, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4
  )
  JOIN `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`  
  USING (network_bin, mask)
)
WHERE city_name  IS NOT null
GROUP BY city_name, geoname_id
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 5000`
```

Find more details on:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2

Comment: FYI - BigQuery deleted this table, so this answer doesn't work anymore. In the meantime here's my solution for Snowflake https://hoffa.medium.com/free-ip-address-geolocation-with-maxmind-and-snowflake-676e74ea80b8

Answer (score 0):

**January 2023 solution**

Just wanted to respond to Felipe's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156309/how-to-get-from-to-ip-address-from-cidr-bigquery#comment132022497_59162947). I'm not sure why he is suggesting an alternate solution using Snowflake, as his existing solution works just fine. The only difference is that you need to create the dataset yourself.

I managed to solve this by going through the exact same steps listed in Felipe's very helpful [original blog article](https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2):

1. Sign-up to MaxMind and download the Geolite2 databases ([link](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data?lang=en))
2. Download the two CSV files `GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4.csv` and `GeoLite2-City-Locations-en.csv`, upload them to a GCP bucket, and create tables from them. I lazily used the BQ automated schema feature and it worked just fine :)
3. Simply create a `geolite2_locs` table using a query similar to the one below (just keep or drop your columns as required for your use-case)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TALBLE `dataset.geolite2_locs` OPTIONS() AS (
SELECT 
  ip_ref.network,
  NET.IP_FROM_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ip_ref.network, r'(.*)/' )) network_bin,
  CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ip_ref.network, r'/(.*)' ) AS INT64) mask,
  ip_ref.geoname_id, 
  city_ref.continent_name as continent_name, 
  city_ref.country_name as country_name,
  city_ref.city_name as city_name,
  city_ref.subdivision_1_name as subdivision_1_name, 
  city_ref.subdivision_2_name as subdivision_2_name, 
  ip_ref.latitude as latitude, 
  ip_ref.longitude as longitude, 
FROM `geolite2`.`geolite2-ipv4` ip_ref LEFT JOIN  `geolite2`.`geolite2-city-en` city_ref USING (geoname_id)
);
```

4. Adapt the query in Felipe's guide or just replace the `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs` with your new table in his answer above.

Should take you at max 1 hour to get this going. Hope it helps.